# Wordpress LIKE query for a glossar page gets wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I know the title is not very catchy, but I'm struggling to find the right terms to describe it in short.

My goal is to have a page that lists all posts in alphanumeric order. Like a glossar. A-Z 0-9.

My problem is that I have a custom query to output the results of a custom post-type. So far so good. 
I also have a modified where clause hooked into `posts_where`

```
// adds a new parameter for WP_QUERY ('starts_with' => $_POST['letter']
function query_starts_with( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $starts_with = $query->get( 'starts_with' );

    if ( $starts_with ) {
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$starts_with%'";
    }

        return $where;
    }

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'query_starts_with', 10, 2 );
```

So I am querying like that:

```
<?php 
     $args = array(
         'post_type'         => 'lexikon',
         'post_status'       => 'publish',
         'starts_with'       => $letter
     ); 

     $qry = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Right now, I have exactly one post inside that post type, which starts with a 'T'.

Im looping through all my disered character via a set array of letters from A-Z and numbers from 0-9, merged together.

```
$a = range('a', 'z');
$b = range('0', '9');

$letters_arr = array_merge($a, $b);
```

So all together im looping with my custom loop:

```
<?php foreach ($letters_arr as $letter) : ?>

<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'lexikon',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'starts_with'       => $letter
); 

$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $qry->have_posts() ) : ?> 

    <?php while ( $qry->have_posts() ) : $qry->the_post(); ?>

        <?php echo strtoupper( $letter ); ?>
        <p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Which gets me the result:

> T Testtitle
>
> 0 Testtitle

So in summary, for some reason, the post that starts with 'T' gets also treated like it starts with a '0' (zero), which I do not understand why.

Can you tell me, whats causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string '0' gets converted to the boolean false, as you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Because of that you don't append your where clause for the letter '0'. Simply change your if from:

```
if ( $starts_with ) {
```

to:

```
if ( $starts_with !== false ) {
```

Comment: Now that you mention the `false`, it makes perfect sense. I had the fear, that I somehow altered the query in a way the it'll always return the 0 due to a faulty check somewhere else. But this simple if-statement just fixed it.